# Whats the best way to code PHP application with a PHP framework that minimises dependencies

Tags: php, symfony, cakephp, zend-framework

I am new to PHP development (and indeed all web development and am undertaking some research on the best way to code against a MVC PHP framework. What I'm looking to find out is whether there is an establised technique to code an application using a PHP framework but to minimise dependency, so that if you wanted to move from 1 framework to another you could do so with minimum effort and without having to start all over again. This is similar to another technique that I've seen with databases - Doctrine, which you can use which provides a generic database layer that you code against so that you don't have strong dependencies to say MySQL or SQLServer etc, so you can switch between them at ease. The PHP frameworks I'm condering are ZendFramework, Symfony & CakePHP.

As a C++/C# developer, my instinct would be to develop a set of generic wrapper classes whose job it is to inteface with the framework such that all the rest of the code has no dependencies on any 1 PHP framework, but I wouldnt want to do this if there is already a library that provides this already. Hope this makes sense.

Effectively, what Im asking is: "Is there a Doctrine equivalent for PHP Frameworks?"

Comment: There is non to my knowledge. but you could write one indeed. However, it will not quickly swappable if you write your own, as you need to write a complete new adapter if you choose to switch. More quickly then if you worked 'native' of course.

Comment: The issue is that each 'php framework' and associated 'orm' have there 'own way' of working. If you pick a 'framework' then you run with it. You can also pick a more 'general php mvc framework' approach by using 'components' (some from 'symfony' others from elsewhere) and a 'simple framework'. i use 'Silex' and 'redbeanphp'.

Answer (score 3):

No. There's not.

The whole point of Frameworks is to provide you with a bunch of stuff to make your life easier and allow you to write less code. This happens by using the features of the framework - ie, making your application dependent on the framework. And each framework is different.

The only way to make your app not depended on a framework is not to use one - which is a silly  approach because it just means more work for you.

I've never heard of Doctrine, but if I understand correctly, it is a completely different scenario. MySQL, PostGres, SQL Server etc are all kind of MEANT to be implementing the same thing - SQL. In cases where there are minor differences in sytax, abstraction layers can account for those thus allowing you to switch between databases easily. In cases where one implements features that another simply does not have, there's nothing an abstraction layer can do to help.

Unlike implementations of SQL, frameworks don't have any agreed upon set of standards, so a way to make it very easy to switch between them isn't really possible.